# Not able to Parse a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting object from back end and in front end I am parsing JSON object but the result I am getting object object.

Here is my Code.

JSON (data contains the following JSON)

```
{
   "sc_sub":"ab",
   "sc_sub1":"abc"
}

var lclObj = JSON.parse(data);
var a = lclObj[0].sc_sub;
```

I made changes to object as array, Now the Problem is I am sending one by one values as array from back end I am getting two arrays as

```
[{
   "sc_sub":"ab",
   "sc_sub1":"abc"
}]

[{
   "sc_sub":"ab",
   "sc_sub1":"abc"
}]
```

How to remove previous array and set new one?

Comment: var a = lclObj.sc_sub;

Comment: Your data is not an `array`

Comment: Also you don't need to parse it if it is not stringified

Comment: If it json is String,then go for >>
var data='{"sc_sub":"ab","sc_sub1":"abc"}'
var lclObj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(lclObj.sc_sub);
else you can go for stringify

Comment: one more question how to remove duplicate objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var useremail =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Data))
```